# How to print debug message for success and failure in ansible wait_for module to test firewall?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

How to print debug message for success and failure having information of destination host on which the task failed in Ansible `wait_for` module to test a firewall?

```yaml
 - name: Check Firewall Connectivity
    wait_for:
      host: 10.200.12.2
      port: 2041
      state: started
      delay: 0
      timeout: 3
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Here is the `debug` you are looking for:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 'Failed with message: ' ~ wait_result.msg if wait_result.failed else 'Success connecting to Firewall' }}"
```

---

You can always [`register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the result of a task in Ansible.
Then based on this result, you can actually act, or print something.

Here is how I would have approached it: I don't know from the top of my head what a task will give me as a result, but I know for a fact that I can `register` it and `debug` it.

So I made this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Check Firewall Connectivity
      wait_for:
        host: 10.200.12.2
        port: 2041
        state: started
        delay: 0
        timeout: 3
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: wait_result

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ wait_result }}"
```

It resulted in this recap:

```
PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [Check Firewall Connectivity] *********************************************
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 3, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:22"}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "elapsed": 3,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:22"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
local                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

So based on this recap, I know that my result have a property `failed` this is going to be `true` if the `wait_for` task fails.
And I even get a `msg` of failure for it.

So now, with the help of the [inline if expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression) of Jinja, I can create this task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 'Failed with message: ' ~ wait_result.msg if wait_result.failed else 'Success connecting to Firewall' }}"
```

This will result in either the recap:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": "Success connecting to Firewall"
}
```

or the recap:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": "Failed with message: Timeout when waiting for 10.200.12.2:2041"
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i have one issue when i add multiple destination hosts and pass it as with_items. wait_result.msg prints "msg": "All items completed", and all the results are under results. 
```bash
wait_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
           {<output of "ansible_loop_var>}
           {<output of "ansible_loop_var>}
           {"item": "10.200.12.1", "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 10.200.12.1:2041"}
          }]
```
whn successful it doesn't give item or msg. tried results.msg and result.item.